# Algorithm: Integer vectors with equal inproduct with a constant vector

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Given vector $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$  and constants $D, e \in \mathbb{Z}$, I need to find all vectors $\vec{x}\in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ such that

$e \geq x_{i} \geq -e$ and $\vec{x} \cdot \vec{a} = D$

Where the inproduct is Euclidean.

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Previously, I just let my computer write down all $\vec{x}$ that fulfill the first equation, and throw out everything that didn't fulfill the second, but as $n$ getls larger, this isn't manageable anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Integer Programming, which is NP-Hard. So no, there isn't an efficient way to solve this. The best you can do is apply relaxation techniques to get some good approximations. A common approach is to treat it as a linear program (look at $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$) and then fine-tune the solution.

The Wikipedia page is a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming